# Adjust layout after using View.gone to delete empty black space

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

i have 3 views of a drawerlayout added using inflater class

```
public View getView(int position, View myView , ViewGroup parent) {

   mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_1,parent,false);

            switch (position % 2) {
                case 0:
                   myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_menu1, parent,
                            false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_menu2, parent,
                            false);
                    break;}}
```

I want to show only the second layout in an if statement (if the user if log in) so I did this

```
              if (position == 1) {

                 if (myUser.IsLogin()){
                    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
              }
```

As you can see in the screenshot below that the first view (yellow stroke )is hidden ,using View.gone but there is black empty space !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eETss.png

I want to adjust the drawer layout so that the black empty space gone once the view is gone!

Thanks

Comment: you tries to set background of myView to transparent?

Comment: How? and why transparent ?

Comment: I want to know which gives you that black color, for myView there isn't a problem as you set it to `GONE`, so there is another layout gives you tyhe black color, may be the main layout or the layout that contains the views

Comment: and it's clear that the other empty space of the screen are black, so it should be the main layout or a container layout, So what's the color you expect in that area? and why you expecting it?

Comment: What are you using for the size of the elements? Fixed height? Weights? Maybe would be better if you add your xml code.